# Smoothing/sampling algorithm has a bug for simple list

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-science, smoothing, graphing

I am trying to smooth a list of numbers, for graphing purposes, I don't want to graph more than about 5000 items, because the render takes too long, and we just don't need extra data.

Imagine we have a simple list:

```
let v = [1,2,3]; // max size is 3
```

we want to add a new data point to the list:

```
v.push(4);
```

but we need to keep the list length to only 3 items. So we need to do something like this:

```
v = [ (1+2)/2, (2+3)/3, (3+4)/4 ];
```

that way, there's only 3 items in the array, but we incorporate all the data.

I have some code that I think does this, but I cannot figure out why it's giving me some weird results, in this case the size is capped at 10, not 3:

```
const util = require('util');

let x = 1;
const values = [];

setInterval(function(){

  values.push(x++);

  if(values.length > 10){

    let prev = values.shift(), curr, i = 0;

    while(true){

      curr = values[i];

      values[i] = (prev + curr)/2;

      if(!values[i+1]){
        break;
      }

      prev = curr;
      i++;

    }

    console.log('after', x, 'new values array:\n', util.inspect(values));
  }

},100);
```

the results look like this:

```
  after: 53 , new values array:
 [ 33.00017937119628,
  35.00004360157914,
  37.00000921602168,
  39.0000016674212,
  41.00000025298232,
  43.00000003129708,
  45.000000003031346,
  47.00000000021555,
  49.000000000010004,
  51.00000000000023 ]
after: 54 , new values array:
 [ 34.00011148638771,
  36.00002640880041,
  38.00000544172144,
  40.00000096020176,
  42.0000001421397,
  44.00000001716421,
  46.00000000162345,
  48.00000000011278,
  50.000000000005116,
  52.000000000000114 ]
after: 55 , new values array:
 [ 35.00006894759406,
  37.000015925260925,
  39.0000032009616,
  41.00000055117073,
  43.000000079651954,
  45.00000000939383,
  47.00000000086811,
  49.00000000005895,
  51.000000000002615,
  53.00000000000006 ]
after: 56 , new values array:
 [ 36.00004243642749,
  38.00000956311126,
  40.000001876066165,
  42.00000031541134,
  44.00000004452289,
  46.00000000513097,
  48.00000000046353,
  50.00000000003078,
  52.000000000001336,
  54.00000000000003 ]
```

but eventually, probably because of floating point numbers, I start to see this:

```
after: 121 , new values array:
 [ 101, 103, 105, 107, 109, 111, 113, 115, 117, 119 ]
after: 122 , new values array:
 [ 102, 104, 106, 108, 110, 112, 114, 116, 118, 120 ]
after: 123 , new values array:
 [ 103, 105, 107, 109, 111, 113, 115, 117, 119, 121 ]
after: 124 , new values array:
 [ 104, 106, 108, 110, 112, 114, 116, 118, 120, 122 ]
```

it might be because of floating point numbers, but weird though.

The **"correct"** result I am looking is a *finite point sample* of all the numbers that have been through the array over time.

Something like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]
```

could get sampled and reduced down to something like this:

```
[1.4, 4.5, 11.2, 16.3, 21.6]
```

hope that makes sense.

Comment: why are you using a while loop and not a for loop?

Comment: Time to debug?.

Comment: That said, I really don't understand what the intent is here.  Your initial description doesn't sound like any conventional smoothing algorithm (why are you *dividing* by the input values?), and I don't understand what this outer loop + shift/push mechanism is intended to represent.

Comment: It might be called a sampling algorithm, not a smoothing algorithm.

Comment: I'm not really sure it's doing either - what does that variable reciprocal represent?

Comment: I updated the question, I made a mistake, the reciprocal was supposed to be 2, fixed it

Comment: I am basically looking for a better smoothing/sampling algorithm than the simple one I have, which doesn't really work.

Comment: Ok, I'm not really sure whether there's a problem any more?  What is wrong with the results in the final snippet?

Comment: The algorithm that I have probably just sucks - I need something better - what I am confused about is why the spread between highest and lowest in the array would converge to exactly 18, I would have expected the spread to grow over time.

Comment: I added more info to the question, this one is inherently difficult to convey but hopefully people understand, perhaps this is better fit for programmers.stackexchange since this is more about how to design an effective sampling algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question properly after a few reads, however when assigning the new array value, you should use: 
`Math.floor( (prev + curr) / 2 )` to return an Int or `( (prev + curr) / 2).toFixed(2)` to return a Float.

Additionally I would explicitly state how many values you are keeping in the array. It is confusing to read

```
 values.push(x++);

 if(values.length > 10){

   while(true)

     if(!values[i+1]){
        break;
     }

   }

 }
```